# extracting zip file to cache file

Tags: python, function, import, python-module, python-zipfile

I am trying to extract the files from the zipfile and add it to a cache file
For a self study in Python.

Do you guys have any tips on how to do it properly ?
Because i have noticed that it makes the cache file but it doesn't add the zipfiles to the cache file.

This is my current code:

```
import os, shutil
from zipfile import ZipFile

path = os.getcwd()
print(path)
cache = os.path.join(path, "files/cache")
print(cache)                                                      
data_path = os.path.join(path, "files/data.zip")
print(data_path)

def clean_cache():
    if os.path.exists(cache):
        shutil.rmtree(cache)
    os.mkdir("files/cache") 

clean_cache()

def cache_zip(zip_path, cache):
    if not os.path.exists(cache):
        os.makedirs(cache)
    with ZipFile(zip_path, 'r') as datazip:
        datazip.extractall(zip_path)

    return

So now i changed my code and now it works.

Was more of a internal problem then the code it self

def cache_zip(zip_path, cache_path):
    with ZipFile(zip_path, 'r') as datazip:
        datazip.extractall(cache_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

`cache_zip` is creating the cache directory if it needs to, but `datazip` does nothing with it. You essentially have `cache_zip` doing two separate operations, neither of which involve moving the extracted files to `cache`

What it seems you actually want is something like this:

```
def cache_zip(zip_path, cache):
    if not os.path.exists(cache):
        os.makedirs(cache)
    with ZipFile(zip_path, 'r') as datazip:
        datazip.extractall(cache)  
        # change 'zip_path' to 'cache' to extract the files to 'cache' instead

    # return  # you don't need to worry about the 'return' here
```